# How to get files list using fileSystem?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to get list of files in specified directory but its throwing error any idea what is implemented wrong in below code.

service.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var async = require('async');
var filePath = path.resolve('./logs/dit/');

  function checkSearchObj ()  {
       fs.readdir(filePath,function (err, files) {
         files.forEach(function(file) {
           console.log(file);
         });
       })
    }

    checkSearchObj();
```

error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at C:\Users\sh529u\WebstormProjects\ulog\app\serverf
s:8:15
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
function checkSearchObj ()  {
   fs.readdir(filePath,function (err, files) {
     files.forEach(function(file) {
       console.log(file);
     });
   })
}
```

to this:

```
function checkSearchObj ()  {
   fs.readdir(filePath,function (err, files) {
     if (err) {
       console.log('Error:', err);
       return;
     }
     files.forEach(function(file) {
       console.log(file);
     });
   })
}
```

to see what's the error.

You need to check for errors instead of assuming that there was no error or otherwise you will try to access undefined variables and the only error you'll see is that you access undefined and not the actual error that's in `err` in this case.

Your callback will either get the `err` or the `files` but not both.

#### Update:

After changing the code to display error you got:

`Error: { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\Web stormProjects\ulog\app\serverfiles\logs\dit'] errno: -4058, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'scandir', path: 'C:\\Users\\sh529u\\WebstormProjects\\ulog\\app\\serverfiles‌​\\logs\\dit'`

Which means that the program doesn't display the files in the directory because there is no such directory. Mystery solved. Now you can see how useful it is to actually check the errors.

Comment: `Error: { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\Web
stormProjects\ulog\app\serverfiles\logs\dit']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\sh529u\\WebstormProjects\\ulog\\app\\serverfiles\\logs\\dit'`

Comment: @hussain So now you see the problem: there is no such directory. See what;s in your `filePath` and make sure you have the directory that you want to access in your file system.

Comment: directory is there as you can see in error i pasted above why its throwing error

Comment: @hussain No, there is no such directory on your file system. Read the error message.

Comment: on root of project i have logs > dit  folders not sure why its using path that shows in error

Comment: Thanks it helps me to drill down to actual issue